# Google Transliteration in Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, richtext, transliteration, google-closure-library

I need to use Google Transliteration along with rich-text editing support.

The Google Transliteration API docs recommend the rich text-editor offered by [Closure library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_editor_Field.html) or [Yahoo! UI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

But, I tried both of them and the transliteration does not work.

Anybody who has implemented a rich-text editor which supports transliteration as well?

[Edit: Answer updated below]

Comment: Hey, Did you find any plugin for this??

Comment: I am also looking for something similar but i could not find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WYSIWIG editor that comes with Textile Markup works well with Google Transliteration API :)

Install the acts_as_textiled plugin

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/defunkt/acts_as_textiled.git
```

and then install textile_editor_helper

```
rails plugin install http://svn.webtest.wvu.edu/repos/rails/plugins/textile_editor_helper
```

Then, you should be able to integrate the WYSIWIG editor in your views. For, MarkitUp fans, equivalent plugins are available too ;)

Refer [this article](http://notepad.onghu.com/2007/3/28/using-textile-editor-plugin-and-acts_as_textiled) for further info. The article explains the editor integration, but the links are outdated, so refer above for the latest sources.

Comment: Can you plz give me the link for Google Transliteration API ?

Answer (score 0):

Id don't think the is one but, as google traduction allows you to translate an entire website, you should be able to do the following:

- Get a PHP page that just ouputs a variable sent as query string
- When you want to translate a page, get the url containing this page's url and the content of the iframe (don't forget to use encodeURIComponent() on it). Then, useencodeURIComponent once more on this string but on all of it and add it to http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.fr&sl=en&tl=fr&twu=1&u=* (* should be your string). That's the url that will give you the exact same content with the exact same format in another language (here, it's from en to fr but you can change it). The problem at this point is that if you put this as url for your iframe, it'll be on another domain and you won't be able to control it anymore. Therefore, you need a PHP page to which you give a url and that outputs the content on you own domain. You get this one and call it with the good query string (you'll have to use encodeURIComponent once again) as src for your iframe and it'll work.

I'm not sure it is understandable. Is it?

Comment: No... The translation I am looking for is real-time that happens as the user types. That's what the transliteration API offers.

Comment: You mean it translate what the user types in the same textarea? o_O

Comment: Well this doesn't really translate the whole thing... It translate words one by one...